# "makefile:1: *** missing separator" in one-line makefile

Tags: cmake

My `makefile` consists of one line

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
```

There are no leading spaces, line ending is UNIX-style. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run input files for `cmake` with `make`.

A `makefile` is input for `make` command.

A `CMakeLists.txt` is input for `cmake` command.

CMake is a build system generator, i.e. it will create a `makefile` from a `CMakeLists.txt` for you, that can later be run with `make`.